# Convex optimization and linear programming please help! :)

Tags: convex-analysis, linear-programming, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

1. How would I write the following as a standard form LP? Minimizing $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i + c\max(a_i-x_i)$ for $a_i \ge 0$ and what is the optimal value for when $c=n$
2. How to express minimize $\frac{1}{2} ||x-y||_2^2$ subj to $y \in K \text{ a closed convex cone}$ as a standard form quadratic program? Why is the solution unique?

For 1, I want something of form min $<c,x>$ sub to $Ax=b$ but how do I take care of the max in my case? For 2, the standard form QP is min $x^TQx+c^Tx$ sub to $Ax=b$. So is it just $\frac{1}{2} (x-y)^T(x-y)$ what are the constraints then? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

(1) : Basically the trick will be to get the $\max$ out of the objective function. Otherwise it's linear, right? So what you do is to add a new variable. Let $t = \max(a_i - x_i)$, or in the form of constraints, $t \geq a_i - x_i$ for all $i$. When you make any of these constraints tight, $t$ will be the maximum of all the $a_i-x_i$.

(2) : Hint: $\|x-y\|_2^2 = \|x\|_2^2+\|y\|_2^2-2\langle x,y\rangle$. Your variable is going to be in the form $\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$, and you can use the fact that $\langle x,y\rangle = x^TIy$. I'll leave the rest to you.

As for $y\in K$, this *is* standard notation for QPs. Unless you have more specifics about how $K$ is constructed, you can't really convert it any further.

Comment: For 1, we want the minimum so then our object becomes min $x+1ct$ sub to $a_i-x_i\le t$

For 2, why is $||x||_2^2+||y||_2^2-2x^TIy$ of the standard QP form? Also why is our min unique?

Comment: I'm trying not to answer *all* of your question for you. I'm trying to give you enough info to work it out. But I'll spell it out: $\begin{pmatrix}x^T & y^T\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}I & -I\\-I & I\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$. *That's* your $x^T Qx$. The solution is unique because you're minimizing a strictly convex function over a convex domain.

Comment: So 1 is correct then? but when I try to find the dual problem solution for it, I get that the gradient with respect to $x$ is equal to 1 always. So I feel like the LP is not correct.

Comment: Yes, your objective is now $\min x+ct$, s.t. $x_i+t\geq a_i$. Why would your gradient be 1? The gradient is a vector.

Comment: Isnt $t \in \mathbb{R}$ not $\mathbb{R}^n$ or do you mean that $t_i\ge a_i - x_i$

Comment: Yes, $t\in\mathbb{R}$. But you'd be taking the gradient over $(x,t)\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

Comment: Right then we have $L(x,t,\lambda) = x+1ct-1\lambda(a_i-x_i-t)$ where $1$ is a vector of ones. Then the gradient is $1+c$ what does it mean to take a gradient w.r.t a scalar and vector?

I also forgot to mention that K is the non negative orthant. Does this allow us to write explicit constraints? Like x>=0

Comment: This is my last comment on this. A vector and a scalar *is* a vector, with one more dimension.

Comment: If K is the non negative orthant. Does this allow us to write explicit constraints? Like $x>=0$. This is last question.

Comment: Yes. It does. I'm done.